# How do I set font-family of chinese characters?

Tags: browser, fonts, css, chinese

Setting the font-family CSS property doesn't seem to have any effect on Chinese characters in either Firefox, Chrome or Safari. Chrome also uses a different font than Firefox and Safari. This is on OS X, I'm not sure about Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Use below font family for chinese characters:

```
body {
  font-family: Hiragino Sans GB', 'Microsoft YaHei', '微軟正黑體', '蘋果儷中黑', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Let me know if you have any query. Hope This will help you.
Thank you.